# MKMapView add annotations in background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mkmapview, android-mapview

When the map is moved the `MKMapView` invokes the delegate function below. Due to the nature of our application we add new vehicles to the map in a separate thread. We have noticed that there is a chance that the application will crash when this code is executed. The error occurs on line 5 in the for loop. Could anyone please explain why the loop is returning nil annotations?

```
func regionDidChange(mapView: MKMapView, animated: Bool) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        var vehiclesToAdd = [VehicleAnnotation]()

        for (var i = 0; i < self.mapView.annotations.count; i++) {
            if (self.mapView.annotations[i].isKindOfClass(VehicleAnnotation)) {
                let vehicleAnnotation: VehicleAnnotation! = self.mapView.annotations[i] as VehicleAnnotation

                if (!MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(vehicleAnnotation.coordinate))) {
                    vehiclesToAdd.append(vehicleAnnotation)
                }
            }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.mapView.addAnnotations(vehiclesToAdd)
        }
    })
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: "Due to the nature of our application we add new vehicles to the map in a separate thread" But there is an immutable law that you must _never_ do _anything_ that affects the interface in a background thread. You are breaking that law. For example you are saying `self.mapView.annotations.count` and `self.mapView.annotations` in the background. No.

Comment: @matt Crap! I hope I'm not in trouble, lol. Could you provide an alternative in an answer? Without the background thread when you move the map it freezes for roughly 5 seconds due to the code in the for loop.

Comment: Also your code makes no sense: you talk of `markersToAdd` and `vehiclesToAdd` as if they were the same thing.

Comment: @matt I apologise for that mistake in my question, I have updated it.

Comment: The code still doesn't make sense.  It is looping through annotations that are _already_ on the map and "adding" them again if they are not currently visible.  What is the exact crash error message and which line exactly is "line 5"?